# Databinding wpf between two encapsulated ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

let me say first that I am not clear about the termonology to use in order to explain my question - please excuse, if I am not clear right away.

Databinding in wpf is not very clear to me and so I can not find a solution to the following problem. I want to refer by databinding in a nested ListView to the dataelement of the containing ListView in which the nested ListView shows up. Probably I am to blind to see the woods becaus auf the trees ...

At the following point:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Id, ElementName=somename}"/>
```

I would like to refer to the dataelement of the containing ListView. Let me give an example:

- John

  1. Monday

     > here I want to use data of John
  2. Tuesday
  3. ...
- Peter
- Tom

The Names are the containing ListView, the Weekdays are the nested ListView.

Of course this is a fictitious example - but the real one would be too complex to explain.

Here is a "complete" code example:

```
                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.PackagingTypeList}" BorderThickness="0" Name="somename" >
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                                    <!--Display Section for the first ListView -->
                                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"  />

                                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PackagingList}" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Packaging_Selected}" >
                                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <WrapPanel  >
                                                                    <!--Display Section for the second ListView -->
                                                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Id}"  />

                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Id, ElementName=somename}"/>

                                                                </WrapPanel>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    </ListView>

                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
```

I would be very thankfull if someone could help me out.

Best regards, 
Fabianus

Comment: Fabianus - You have a nested ListView but your DataContext is not nested in nature. I mean that Outer Class (should be bound to outer ListView) and it should have the List<T> of Items that should be bound to Inner ListView.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to go.. But you could try with: {Binding somename, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=ListView} inside the Binding. Go up 2 levels for finding type of ListView

Comment: It's tricky following exactly what is meant but I think maybe that should be {Binding DataContext.somepropertyname, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=ListViewItem}

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your help !

Finally both solution do work :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Id, ElementName=somename}"/>


<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
```